# Lista python necesito que no se repitan

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, python-requests

Muy buen dia a todos queria que me pudieran ayudar tengo el siguiente código y necesito que en estos grupos al imprimirlos los resultados sean diferentes equipos según los grupos por que al imprimir me estan apareciendo los mismos equipos. les agradezco mucho la verdad no he trabajado
en python por eso hago la pregunta, este es el resultado necesito que sea diferente por grupo

[image: este es el resultado necesito que sea diferente por grupo]
este seria mi codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema esta en que estas asignando las variables `Primergrupo` y `SegundoGrupo` con los mismos valores, cuando deberias iterar las variables anteriores (´Santander, SerieA, PremierLeague, Bundesliga´) para que cambien sus valores. Puedes hacerlo declarando una funcion:

```py
import random
lista1 = ['Barcelona', 'Madrid', 'Real Sociedad', 'Atletico' ]
lista2 = ['Juventus', 'Lazio', 'Inter Milan', 'Atlanta']
lista3 = ['Liverpool', 'M.City', 'Leicester City', 'Chealse']
lista4 = ['Bayern Munich', 'Borussia Dortmun', 'RB Leipzip', 'Borussia Monchengladbach']

def armar_grupo(lista1, lista2, lista3, lista4)
    Santander = (random.choice(lista1))
    SerieA = (random.choice(lista2))
    PremierLeague = (random.choice(lista3))
    BundesLiga = (random.choice(lista4))
    return (Santander, SerieA, PremierLeague, BundesLiga)

PrimerGrupo = armar_grupo(lista1, lista2, lista3, lista4)
SegundoGrupo = armar_grupo(lista1, lista2, lista3, lista4)

print(PrimerGrupo, SegundoGrupo)
```

Tambien puedes iterar con un ciclo `for`:

```py
import random
lista1 = ['Barcelona', 'Madrid', 'Real Sociedad', 'Atletico' ]
lista2 = ['Juventus', 'Lazio', 'Inter Milan', 'Atlanta']
lista3 = ['Liverpool', 'M.City', 'Leicester City', 'Chealse']
lista4 = ['Bayern Munich', 'Borussia Dortmun', 'RB Leipzip', 'Borussia Monchengladbach']

grupos = [0] * 2
for i in range(2)
    Santander = (random.choice(lista1))
    SerieA = (random.choice(lista2))
    PremierLeague = (random.choice(lista3))
    BundesLiga = (random.choice(lista4))
    grupos[i] = (Santander, SerieA, PremierLeague, BundesLiga)

print(grupos[0], grupos[1])
```

Y por ultimo, si quieres que los equipos sean totalmente diferentes, te convendria utilizar un ciclo while, en una funcion que te permita leer todo el array y tomar cualquier valor diferente a otro valor pasado por parametro, de la siguiente forma:

```py
def elegir_diferente(valor, array):

   result = random.choice(array)
   while valor == result:
      result = random.choice(array)
   return result
```

Lo agregas cuando seleccionas el segundo grupo...

```py
PrimerGrupo = armar_grupo(lista1, lista2, lista3, lista4)
SegundoGrupo = (elegir_diferente(PrimerGrupo[0], lista1), 
                elegir_diferente(PrimerGrupo[1], lista2), 
                elegir_diferente(PrimerGrupo[2], lista3), 
                elegir_diferente(PrimerGrupo[3], lista4))
```

Personalmente evitaria hacerlo asi porque este codigo no seria muy reutilizable para casos en los que quieras obtener mas de dos grupos sin repeticion, pero si solo te limitas a dos en suficiente, el resto depende de la imaginacion jaja.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ayudado mucho solamente una consulta como puedo hacer que no se me repitan los equipos de ambos grupos, disculpa la molestia que siempre sean diferentes en ambos grupos

Comment: Agregue tu duda a la respuesta anterior